What is the maximum RAM for Dell Vostro 220s? (4 or 8 GB?)
I've seen both 4GB and 8GB indicated on various sites. Could not find anything on Dell.

I've seen both 4GB and 8GB indicated on various sites.
The maximum memory is 4GB:

Minimum memory 512 MB
Maximum memory 4 GB

Source: Dell™ Vostro™ 420/220/220s
Setup and Quick Reference Guide
